# Visual studio 2019 настройка редактора кода

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Не могу найти, где сделать чтобы форматирование кода было так:

```
void method() {
    //.. code
}
```

А не так:

```
void method() 
{
    //.. code
}
```

Я уже привык, когда скобки начинаются с той-же строки и заканчиваются на следующей.

И где убрать эту дебильную возможность, сначала нажимаем `CTRL+E`, а только потом `CTRL+D` и все комбинации по форматированию работают только после `CTRL+E`, а только потом работает любая другая комбинация, уж очень напрягает это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tools -> options -> text editor -> code style -> formatting -> new lines
```

убираем 2 первые галочки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройка комбинаций клавиш:

```
tools -> options -> environment -> keyboard
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решил, а как мне убрать `CTR+E`, чтобы без нее работали команды?